# Make a radial gradients radius 200px

Tags: css, radial-gradients

How would I make the radius 200px in width and height? I've read that this can be done in pixel units, but every attempt has failed.

```
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(75% 100%, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 33%);
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(75% 19%, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 33%);
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(75% 19%, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 33%);
background-image: radial-gradient(75% 19%, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 33%)
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(75% 19%, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 33%);
```

Comment: Radius is half the diameter: if the radius was 200px then it would be **400px** in width and height, so this question should be "radius 100px".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**edit**: Updated for modern syntax, I've left the original below for a record of the 2011 syntax

---

You can set both the radius and position the gradient in pixel values or any other valid [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/length) unit.

In the example below `circle at 200px 200px` is setting the center point of the circle to 200px across and 200px down, this could also be any value accepted by [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) such as left or top.

The next values are the color stops and are comma separated pairs of `color length`. Again any valid value of [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) and [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/length) would work `red 10%`, `#333 10px` and `rgb(10,47,10) 1em` would all be valid.

Values like px or em are absolute and percentage values would be relative to the gradient container.

```css
.gradient-demo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 200px 200px, #fff 0px, #fff 100px, #ff7ae9 101px);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-demo"></div>
```

---

### **Original Answer:**

> ```
> background-image:    -moz-radial-gradient(50px 100px, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 200px);
> background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50px 100px, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 200px);
> background-image:      -o-radial-gradient(50px 100px, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 200px);
> background-image:     -ms-radial-gradient(50px 100px, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 200px);
> background-image:         radial-gradient(50px 100px, circle farthest-corner, #ffffff, #ff7ae9 200px);
> ```
>
> In this example the '200px' is the size of the circle, any standard
> CSS units such as px, em or percentages are fine.
>
> The '50px 100px' is the position of the centre of the circle, it works
> the same way as [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position) so values like 'left top' are
> fine too.
>
> There are a few [online generators](http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index.html#background-image:%20radial-gradient%2860%25%2020%25,%20circle%20farthest-side,%20#ffff4d,%20#a9de4d%20100px%29) that can help you with all the
> vendor specific prefixes.
>
> ---
>
> p.s.   @Mohsen pixel values are fine, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-radial-gradient#Values) says:
>
> > either a percentage between 0% and 100% or a length along the gradient axis
>
> If you click on '[length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/length)' it says
>
> > The CSS syntax for length is a number followed immediately by a unit. Space between the number and the unit is not allowed.

Comment: Did you applied your CSS to an element? It's not valid

Comment: Not working, it isn't valid css

Comment: @AshleyFernandes This is an answer from 12 years ago, things have changed a bit! You certainly don't need the vendor prefixed versions any more. Check the MDN link in the answer for the modern syntax. Something like `background: radial-gradient(red 30px, yellow 200px, #1e90ff 300px)` should work with pixel values

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit the answer with the new values

Comment: @AshleyFernandes  Have updated

Comment: The OP asked for a circle with **radius** 200px, but this CSS gives a circle with **diameter** 200px - using `circle at 200px 200px` says "there is a circle at (200,200)" but it does not actually define its size or radius - but the CSS here still works because gradient-images are (by default) sized to fit the element's box, which incidentally is 200px tall, so this code won't keep a constant-sized circle if the element is resized.